# How to add pick-list field while using LDS

Tags: lightning-data-service, data-service

I am not able to display the salutation pick-list field on the lightning component, I have tried lightning:recordEditForm and force:recordData

Can someone please suggest the right path to show the pick-list field by using LDS?

Using lightning:recordEditForm

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />

        <lightning:card iconName="action:add_contact" title="Add Contact">
            <div class="slds-p-around_small">
            <lightning:recordEditForm 
                                      objectApiName="Contact"
                                      onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">
                <lightning:messages />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="salutation" />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="FirstName" />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="LastName" />
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
                <lightning:inputField fieldname="Languages__c" />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Birthdate" />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Phone" />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Email" />
                <lightning:button aura:id="submit" type="submit" label="Save record" class="slds-m-top_medium" />
            </lightning:recordEditForm>
            <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
            </div>
        </lightning:card>   
</aura:component>
```

Using Force:recordData

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="newContact" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="simpleNewContact" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="newContactError" type="String"/>
    <force:recordData aura:id="contactRecordCreator"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      targetRecord="{!v.newContact}"
                      targetFields ="{!v.simpleNewContact}"
                      targetError="{!v.newContactError}"
                      />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <!-- Display the new contact form -->
    <div class="Create Contact">
        <lightning:card iconName="action:new_contact" title="Create Contact">
            <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
                <lightning:input aura:id="contactField" label="Salutation " value="{!v.simpleNewContact.Salutation}"/>
                <lightning:input aura:id="contactField" label="First Name" value="{!v.simpleNewContact.FirstName}"/>
                <lightning:input aura:id="contactField" label="Last Name"  required="true" value="{!v.simpleNewContact.LastName}"/>
                <lightning:input aura:id="contactField" label="Title" value="{!v.simpleNewContact.Title}"/>
                <br/>
                <lightning:button label="Save Contact" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.handleSaveContact}"/>
            </div>
        </lightning:card>
    </div>
    <!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors -->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.newContactError))}">
        <div class="recordError">
            {!v.newContactError}</div>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Name:- The contact’s combined first name, middle name, last name, and
>   suffix, as displayed on the contact detail page.

- Lightning:RecordEditForm inherit the property of the field, it will show
  the field in their datatype whereas all the fields in
  Force:RecordData will be shown as Text field.

Instead of using FirstName, LastName separately and go for Salutation custom picklist because it is not available in Salesforce to use it as a separate field, You Can use Name field in Lightning:RecordEditForm to display all the three fields as follows:-

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />

        <lightning:card iconName="action:add_contact" title="Add Contact">
            <div class="slds-p-around_small">
            <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Contact">
                <lightning:messages />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Birthdate" />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Phone" />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Email" />
                <lightning:button aura:id="submit" type="submit" label="Save record" class="slds-m-top_medium" />
            </lightning:recordEditForm>
            </div>
        </lightning:card>   
</aura:component>
```

Here is the screenshot:-

[image]